# Primefaces Charts don't work in IE 7/8

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I got a problem that i can't put my primefaces charts working on IE 7/8.

The nice part is that primefaces.org demo showcase work in all IE's, but i can't figure it out, how they do that.

Someone have idea on how they do that?

Thanks

Comment: What specifically is your problem with Primefaces chart controls?  What version of Primefaces are you using?  I believe you need to download and include JFreeReport jars in your application.  The specific requirements for these components are listed in the documentation.

Comment: Hi, i have the last version. Everything works fine in Chrome and IE9 but in IE 8 and 7 it doesn't work

Comment: Have you checked the doctype difference between the demo and your project?

Comment: yep, its the same (!DOCTYPE html)